# How to draw a curve through every point.

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

I have x,y coordinates.
They are arranged at fixed intervals of 1 unit along the x axis.
The Y values are arbitrary.
I want to draw smooth curvy line that passes through all of them. Or rather, I want a formula to find the y for any value of x for the hypothetical line.

Comment: This asks for an *interpolation* of the $(x,y)$ coordinates "arranged at fixed intervals", or if you intend to "find the $y$ for any value of $x$" this would be *extrapolation* when $x$ falls outside the intervals of given coordinates.  A good interpolation procedure is chosen based on what you plan to do with the curve; there is no single best procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few methods you can use:

1. Simply interpolate them using a bunch of quadratics. The resulting curve will have discontinuous 2nd derivative.
2. [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)
3. Discrete Fourier transform

Answer (score 1):

Cubic (or other degree) splines.
That way you can make the curve
as smooth as you want.